# How to get modified fields submitted with auto refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a web page that automatically refreshes. I am trying to find a way to have changes the user has made to fields on the page submitted so they are picked up by the automatic refresh and sent to the server. I know I can use ajax to pass them back and save them somewhere on the server side, but this seems like overkill. I'd have to make an ajax call every time a field is changed. Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this?

The auto refresh is achieved via this code that is in every page as part of the head:

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);
function doLoad()
{ setTimeout( "refresh()", 30*1000 ); }
function refresh()
{ window.location.href = sURL; }
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function refresh()
{ window.location.replace( sURL ); }
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function refresh()
{ window.location.reload( true ); }
//-->
</script>
```

As well as this as part of the body:

```
<body onload="doLoad()">
```

Comment: Just to get some context, how does the page automatically refresh? Sounds like you are doing something like `location.reload()` on a setInterval.

Comment: I've updated my question to show how the refresh is achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**
This should submit the form after 30 seconds.

```
// Can't do anything with those that have javascript disabled.
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);
function doLoad()
{ setTimeout( "document.myrefreshform.submit()", 30*1000 ); }
</script>
```

Comment: I've updated my question to show how the refresh is achieved.

Comment: Actually the row `var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);` is unnecessary aswell, I copied your solution and accidentally left it in...

Comment: I didn't write that code, I inherited it. And I really don't understand how it works - why there's 3 functions with the same name - and why if I remove any of those functions it either doesn't refresh at all, or when it refreshes it get's an 'untrusted connection' error.

Comment: As long as you keep `var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);`
`function doLoad() { setTimeout( "refresh()", 30*1000 ); }` and one of the `reload()` functions, it should still work. In my opinion, this shouldn't happen - you should be able to remove any of these. There was probably something wrong with the way you removed them, perhaps a syntax error.

Comment: In one comment you said "the row var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname); is unnecessary" and then in another "As long as you keep var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname); ..."

Comment: As long as you keep `function doLoad() { setTimeout( "refresh()", 30*1000 ); }` and one of the `reload()` functions, it should still work. 
That copy-paste....